# Where I can find the CI service for Symfony project?

Tags: symfony

Is the projects **symfony/var-dumper**, **symfony/process** and **symfony/routing** using continuous integration services (e.g., Travis-CI or Jenkins)? Or has it used at any point of its lifetime?

Comment: There is a `.travis.yml` and a `.appveyor.yml` so I suppose yes.

Comment: Is there any special background for your question?

Comment: Actually i made the wrong question. I shouldnt ask for the symfony/symfony it was a mistake. I was intrested in the repos **symfony/var-dumper**, **symfony/process** and **symfony/routing**. The question is: are these projects using CI? Or they are integrated only when a new build of symfony is launched?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does use Travis CI and AppVeyor (see https://travis-ci.org/symfony/symfony and https://ci.appveyor.com/project/fabpot/symfony).

Comment: Actually i made the wrong question. I shouldnt ask for the symfony/symfony it was a mistake. I was intrested in the repos symfony/var-dumper, symfony/process and symfony/routing. The question is: are these projects using CI? Or they are integrated only when a new build of symfony is launched?

Comment: These repositories are read-only subtree splits of the main `symfony/symfony` repository. They don't have CI jobs as all changes are triggered through the main repository where all tests are run on AppVeyor and Travis CI.